# Python requests при post запросе встречается капча

Tags: python, requests, recaptcha

Стоит задача купить определённый товар на Binance NFT (https://www.binance.com/en/nft/blindBox/market?theme=126206614880739328).
Я использую python requests для отправки post запроса.
Если я нажимую на кнопку покупки, то в network отправляется post запрос на recaptcha.net
[image: вот он]

Как это  можно обойти или пройти, если она даже не видна мне?

Comment: Получилось продвинуться в решении вопроса?

Comment: @Dilitand бесплатно обойти это не как не возможно не используя selenium.

Comment: Никак. Это и есть защита от подобных ботов )

Comment: Captcha.guru попробуй, обходит каптчу